# File opening with only base name in C

Tags: c, file

In C , How to open a file by considering only base name of the file for example there may be any name in the suffix part of file but the base name will be same like  Unit_123, Unit_245, Unit_658.

In C , I have to give only base name, irrespective of any suffix like 123, 245, 658 by giving only base name the file should open.

In Linux shell script, this can be achieved by giving file name followed by as astreix(*), for example if we give Unit* irrespective of suffix it will take the file name.. how to achieve this in c

Comment: As your *first* question on Stack Overflow, this question is not so bad. Welcome to Stack Overflow. However, we can only guess that you mean for your C program to run in the Linux operating system, but we can't be completely sure that is why you compared with Linux shell. So if you can edit your question, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way in C to do this. It is operating system dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the files in a directory with wildcards. The C standard doesn't provide any function for this, but there are, of course, platform-dependent solutions:

On Linux or other Posix ststelms, you can use [glob (3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob), which can take wildcards like those understood in the shell.

On Windows, there is [FindFirstFile and FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which takes at least asterisks and question marks as wildcards.

Comment: +1, I would have written something like this if I had not been in a hurry. :)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want in C, the standard way would involve getting a directory listing for the directory holding the files of interest. If the files are located in a single directory, then the function `scandir` will fill the `dirent` struct with filenames from the directory. `scandir` takes as its **3rd** argument a filter function of the type:

```
int (*filter)(const struct dirent *)
```

This allows you to match only the filenames that satisfy the criteria you provide in the `filter` function.

If you need to search a directory-tree for files/sub-directories, then functions you want are `ftw` and `nftw`. Both can return listings of the files and/or sub-directories present (depending on the `FLAGS`) which can then be parsed for the matching files. Take a look at all and decide what will fit your needs the best.

None of these functions represent the only way to obtain and parse file listings in C. They are simply the general functions that come to mind to do what you describe.

Comment: And this of course, is for Linux. (For other operating systems, it would be different.) Just pointing out for completeness, your answer is good. +1